# How do i set custom permissions to a custom module i made in ORCHARD

Tags: module, permissions, content-management-system, orchardcms

i made a module called NEWS module and i want to set custom permissions for the same for example i want the DASHBOARD to hide delete button when a editor logs in 
this is my permission.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Orchard.Environment.Extensions.Models;
using Orchard.Security.Permissions;

namespace News
{

    public class Permissions : IPermissionProvider

    {
        public static readonly Permission ManageNews = new Permission { 

Description = "Manage News", Name = "ManageNews" };

        public virtual Feature Feature { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Permission> GetPermissions()
        {
            return new[] {
                ManageNews,
            };
        }

        public IEnumerable<PermissionStereotype> GetDefaultStereotypes()
        {
            return new[] {
                new PermissionStereotype {
                    Name = "Administrator",
                    Permissions = new[] { ManageNews }
                },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

any help is welcomed.

Comment: http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Custom-permissions/